# file I/O in Spidermonkey

Tags: javascript, python, spidermonkey

Thanks to `python-spidermonkey`, using JavaScript code from Python is really easy.

However, instead of using Python to read JS code from a file and passing the string to Spidermonkey, is there a way to read the file from within Spidermonkey (or pass the filepath as an argument, as in Rhino)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you can just bind a Python function and use it from within Spidermonkey:
http://davisp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/26898/tickets/23-support-for-file-io-js_evaluatescript

```
import spidermonkey

def loadfile(fname):
    return open(fname).read()

rt = spidermonkey.Runtime()
cx = rt.new_context()
cx.add_global("loadfile", loadfile)
ret = cx.execute('var contents = loadfile("foo.js"); eval(contents);')
```

Answer (score 2):

The SpiderMonkey as a library allows that by calling the [`JS_EvaluateScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference/JS_EvaluateScript) with a non-NULL `filename` argument.

However, the [interfacing code](http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/source/browse/trunk/spidermonkey.pyx) of `python-spidermonkey` calls `JS_EvaluateScript` only inside the `eval_script` method, which as coded supplies source only as a string.

You should address your issue to the python-spidermonkey developer, or —better, if possible!— provide a patch for a, say, `eval_file_script` method :)